# Merge {incompatibility} into {conflicts}

Tags: discussion, tagging

As the title says: the tags [conflicts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts) and [incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incompatibility) seem to cover the same ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I merged [conflicts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts) and [incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incompatibility), choosing [incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incompatibility) as main tag and [conflicts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflicts) as synonym.

I preferred [incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incompatibility) because it has a wider meaning, covering also undesired behavior even without a conflict.

Comment: Should it be {incompatibilities}?

Comment: I thought about it, as we prefer plural forms. I think it's ok in singular as a state or quality, not so much used in plural. The singular also wins by hits in a google search. But fine, if your comment get's 5 upvotes more than mine I'll rename immediately to the longer tag name. ;-)

Comment: If anybody prefers [tag:conflicts] as the main tag instead, upvote this comment.

Comment: Re "singular also wins by hits in a google search": That's also true for "error" v. {errors}. ;-)